# Stranger error in SqlAlchemy. Bug?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I tried to use Flask-Restful + SqlAlchemy (with Automap) + MySql SGDB but I don't understand why this error occured in my code:

I sent the request in my controller and it worked normally, but after 10s an error is generated about a loss of connection with a SGDB.

```
itens = session.query(estados).filter(estados.ativo == True)
```

But stranger is that if I use SQL string syntax, the problem does not occur.

```
itens = engine.execute("SELECT `TBEstados`.`id`, `TBEstados`.`nome`, `TBEstados`.`ativo` FROM `intbr_webapp`.`TBEstados`;")
```

I'm using SqlAlchemy 1.2 but I did try also the 1.1 version. I did try also use the `pre-ping=true` and I didn't obtain success.

Does someone know anything about this? I don't understand why using ORM structure doesn't work, but with SQL syntax it does work. The connection is same, but the result is not.

My code is below:

## estado.py

```
from flask import jsonify
from flask_restful import Resource
from json import dumps
from resources.database import Base, session, engine
#from resources.dataEncoder import JsonModel
from models.TBEstados import TBEstadosSchema

class Estados(Resource):
    def get(self):            
        estados = Base.classes.TBEstados
        itens = session.query(estados).filter(estados.ativo == True)
        result = TBEstadosSchema(many=True).dump(itens)
        return jsonify(result.data)
```

## database.py (imported in EstadoModel)

```
from flask import Flask, g
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = my conn string

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE'] = 3600
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_TIMEOUT'] = 30

Base = automap_base()
engine = create_engine(app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'], pool_pre_ping=True)
# reflect the tables
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

ma = Marshmallow()
```

## run.py

```
from flask import Flask, g
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
import resources.database
from controllers.Estados import Estados

app = Flask(__name__)

api = Api(app)
api.add_resource(Estados, '/estados')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=9002)
```

The exact error:

**sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query') [SQL: 'SELECT `TBEstados`.id AS `TBEstados_id`, `TBEstados`.nome AS `TBEstados_nome`, `TBEstados`.ativo AS `TBEstados_ativo` \nFROM `TBEstados` \nWHERE `TBEstados`.ativo = true']**

Comment: Using engine directly will use a different connection per executed statement or so, depending on your configuration, where as the session will hold on to a connection until closed.

Comment: please show the code where you are creating the `estados` object in ORM (either declarative_base or metadata). Is your sqlalchemy objects in the same module as the `query` or imported from different module?

Comment: Also please post the exact error you got in context.

Comment: Thanks for help. I edited my question inserting more details about error. I don't understand because the error not occur when I use SQL string. My session object is the same, using "engine.execute(SQL)" and error not occur!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem!

I changed value of the MySql variable *wait_timeout* of the "10s" to 100s (to test) and error in SqlAlchemy using PyMySql provider doesn't occurred again.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout

Thanks for help!